# Gradually increasing cpu usage without memory increase. Ideas?

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, debugging, cpu-usage

So I have an app written in C++, running on Ubuntu 12.04, that initially reads some data from the db, then watches a directory for files. When they show up, it processes them, then writes some data back to the db. Over time, the cpu usage gradually increases, on the order of about 5% per day, but the memory usage stays the same. Logically it looks like this:

```
-open db connect
-while(keep_running())
    - check dir for new files (I know - it should use the watch system and callbacks, but..)
    - process files
    - (possibly) update db
-end while
-close db connect
```

Where keep_running() is always true until you SIGINT

The code is not that complicated, so I'm at a loss for the cpu usage - callgrind looks right. I suspect the db connection, but that hasn't exhibited this behavior in other similar apps. My next step is attaching valgrind to a process and letting it run for a few days - in the mean time, anything else I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to not be the db portion - someone was using a .find() on a huge map object. It's one call buried in a bunch of db sections, which is why I was leaning toward the db.

Nothing to see here, carry on :)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't surprising.  As you describe the application, the database tables are getting larger.

Queries on larger tables probably take a bit more CPU.  You don't describe the tables, indexes, or queries, but the behavior is reasonable.

You won't necessarily see an increase in space used by the database, because databases typically reserve extra space on disk for growing tables.

Comment: So perhaps optimizing the update queries? It's currently an INSERT INTO (blah) VALUES (blah) Is there a better way?

Comment: @codeMonkey_39 . . . Your question is general.  My answer is general.  From what you say, increased CPU is due to increased data size.  There are probably ways to make the code more efficient, but analysis of an entire application is outside the scope of this forum.

Comment: So an INSERT on a large table of entries takes longer than an INSERT on a smaller? I don't know much about databases, but that seems counter-intuitive...

Comment: @codeMonkey_39 . . . The size of a table would have little impact directly on an insert (there are extreme situations).  It could affect index insertion time (O(log(n)) time).  Updates, on the other hand, would be affected by table size once a table doesn't fit into memory, because the probably of finding the page in the cache would decrease with page size.  (Your sample code says "update" not "insert".)  This can also get more complicated with triggers and constraints.